# Find $E[Z^2(t)]$ when $Z(t) = X(t) - Y(t)$ where $Y$ is the output of a LTI system with WSS process $X$ as its input

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, autocorrelation, cross-correlation, adaptive-filters

I received this as a practice problem (part b only).

[image: Let Y(t) = h(t) * X(t) and Z(t) = X(t) - Y(t). Find E(Z^2(t))]

I was able to figure out that $E[Z^2(t)]$ = $R_X(0)+R_Y(0)-2R_\text{XY}(0)$ but did not see how to continue.

Checking the answers, I saw this line of reasoning:
[image: expected value of the square of z of t equals negative 2 times the integral from negative infinity to infinity of h of r times autocorrelation of x of negative r times dr]

Both steps do not make sense to me; it seems as if a few steps that should have been in between were left out. Could somebody provide some explanation?

Comment: I think you mean *I was able to figure out that $\mathbb{E}[Z^2(t)] = R_X(0) + R_Y(0) -2R_{XY}(0)$*

Comment: Ah, yep. I wrote it down wrong. Let me edit that

Comment: Is $X(t)$ given to be a WSS process but you just haven't bothered to mention it?

Comment: Yes, it's a WSS process.

Comment: Then why don't you _edit_ your question to state this in the question itself?

Comment: Ok, I just did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Setting aside complete mathematical rigor, and assuming $x(t)$ is a WSS process, let's start with the definitions*:

**Convolution** $$h(t) * x(t) =
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(\tau)x(t-\tau)d\tau$$
**Cross-correlation**
$$R_{XY}(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)y(t+\tau)dt$$
**Auto-correlation (note the symmetry):**
$$R_{X}(\tau) = R_{X}(-\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)x(t+\tau)dt$$

---

- Let's start with the $R_{XY}(0)$ term: \begin{align} R_{XY}(0) &=   
     \int x(t)y(t)dt\\ &=    \int x(t)\left(\int h(r)x(t-r)dr\right)dt\\  
     &=    \int h(r)\left(\int x(t)x(t-r)dt\right)dr\\    &= \int
     h(r)R_X(-r)dr\\ \end{align}
- Now the $R_{Y}(0)$ term:
  \begin{align}
   R_{Y}(0) &=
     \int y(t)y(t)dt\\ &=
     \int \biggl(\int h(r)x(t-r)dr\biggr)\biggl(\int h(s)x(t-s)ds\biggr)dt\\
     &=
     \int \int h(s)h(r)\biggl( \int x(t-r)x(t-s)dt \biggr)dsdr\end{align}
  Now set $a = t - r$ and use the auto-correlation symmetry property:
  \begin{align}
  R_{Y}(0) &=
     \int \int h(s)h(r)\biggl( \int x(a)x(a+r-s)da \biggr)dsdr\\
  &=
     \int \int h(s)h(r)R_X(r-s)dsdr\\
  &=
     \int \int h(s)h(r)R_X(s-r)dsdr
  \end{align}

Comment: If that's true, why isn't the final answer $E[X^2(t)] + $ (your value for $R_Y(0)$) - 2*(your answer for $R_\text{XY}(0)$)?

Comment: @RobertMoore It is... check again ;)

Comment: Oh my, I hallucinated an equals sign on the last line of the solution screenshot in my question!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help